# how do I clear these errors and turn this code into a document using latex in codio?

Tags: tables, fonts, spacing, graphics, floats

[image]

I'm using latex inside of codio for class and can't turn code into pdf. the errors are keeping me from compiling and turning this into a pdf document.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: it can't find the image file that you are trying to include. Double check that the image file, with that precise name, does in fact reside in the same folder as the TeX file you are trying to build.

Comment: Welcome! Please never post pictures of code. Instead, make a small example which demonstrates the problem and paste the code here as text.

Comment: I am not sure that the option `max width` exists for the `\includegraphics` command. But you don't show the document set up, so I can't tell for sure.

Comment: @JasperHabicht The `max width` option comes from `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`

Comment: \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}??? how do I adjust to make it work??

Comment: Welcome, @Sherrod. // Please create a new Latex file you can post here, with these features: a) code compiles, when we copy it (e.g. starts with \documentclass, mentions relevant packages etc.), b) is short BUT still shows your problem, c) please post your image you try to load, to. This will improve answers considerably. Thank you